# Asus x205ta cannot boot from USB

Tags: bootable-media

My Asus x205ta does not boot from USB. I have disabled secure boot and it still does not show me the bootable USB as an option in the boot menu.

Answer (score 2):

Asus X205TA requires a UEFI-bootable disk to boot from. Based on your firmware version you can also boot from UEFI-CSM. For UEFI-CSM, go to BIOS (Hit Esc when the computer starts, choose the last option), and if you see the `Enable Legacy CSM` option then select it.

For UEFI, use the tool [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and select option `MBR partitioning scheme for UEFI`. You'll have to be careful that once you give the path to the ISO, it may change this option (cost me quite a bit of time). So before hitting start, check again.

Comment: what firmware version is required for UEFI-CSM? I have a X205TA and don't see anything about `Enable Legacy CSM` in my BIOS

Comment: @sixty4bit Sorry the computer is with my grandmother now who can't look that up...

Comment: Not only UEFI, but it appears to be 32-bit EFI only (even though the CPU is 64-bit): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_x205ta#Booting_Arch_install_media

Answer (score 0):

Just create a UEFI bootable UEFI,then try to boot it.
when using a utility like Rufus to create a bootable USB drive just select "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" in the "partition scheme and target system type" section.....................by default it is set to "MBR partition scheme for BIOS and UEFI-CSM"..............but unfortunately this cannot be used to create a bootable USB in a system that doesn't have legacy support..................try it.......it worked for me  ;)